# Stepper motor getting very hot: wrong driver or power supply?

Tags: power-supply, driver, schematics, stepper-motor, heat

I have built a simple driver circuit for an unipolar stepper motor, based on an ULN2003A. The schematic:

[image]

The motor is a PM25L. Data sheet is [here](http://www.eminebea.com/content/html/en/motor_list/pm_motor/pdf/pm25l024.pdf).

It was salvaged from an old electric typewriter, and the ULN2003A and Zener from the driver board inside the same device. It's a 5 wires motor, but the one in the schematic is 6 wires. I suppose the only difference is that the 5 wire version has the two center taps joined together so that's what you see in my schematic.

The Zener diode is an [HZ-361](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet2/2/05jau9cjylkj1e73ox1pcilug03y.pdf)
According to the datasheet the Vz is 34.2, so it's above 2x the power supply voltage.

I am feeding the motor from a laptop variable power supply. The lowest it can run it is 9.5V and it's rated at 3.5A at that voltage.

The motor seems to run perfectly, however after a minute or so it becomes extremely hot. I don't have anything to measure the actual temp but it is painful to put my fingers on it for more than half a second.

As suggested below by Russell McMahon I also did the following extra test:

- given the circuit above, add a 25V 100uF cap between COM and GND. operate motor. measured voltage across the cap is around 22V
- given the circuit above, remove the zener and leave COM pin floating: nothing bad happens to the ULN2003A, the motor runs well but still overheats
- given the circuit above, remove the zener and put a resitor and a 100uF 25V capacitor in series between COM and GND (COM -> R -> C -> GND): the motor runs well but still overheats

Comment: Missed the rated voltage in the datasheet. Makes my answer irrelevant, so I've deleted it.

Comment: @stevenvh just to clarify, are you confirming that 9.5V is within the limits of what voltages the motor can run on ?

Comment: it says drive voltage 12V, doesn't it? So 9.5V should be alright.

Comment: What is the zener voltage? The supply voltage needs to be lower than the zener voltage? Also, what is the zener voltage?

Comment: Hot sounds wrong. What is the coil resistane when measured with an ohm meter (multimeter) center tap to any conmnected phase?  What is the supply current? | If you have a 50 ohm coil then the power per phase max should be V^2/R = 144/50 = 2.9 Watt. Overall yu should not have more than the equivalent of 1  phase being driven cintinually. 3 Watt sis not vast heat wise. | IF you have the 8 Ohm version ... :-). | 12^2/8 = 18W or I = V/R = 12//8 = 1.5A = hotter than 3 Watts.| 8 ohm version is made to be pulse driven (or with series R).

Comment: The measured R between center tap and any coil is around 35 ohm (looks like these motors can have [custom resistances](http://eminebea.com/content/html/en/engineering/motors/pm_motor/selection_pm/resistance.shtml)). | Therefore power per phase should be 4W | I guess it falls in the same ballpark as the 3W case, so it should not run hot. | But I also found [this page](http://eminebea.com/content/html/en/engineering/motors/pm_motor/selection_pm/temperature.shtml) about temperature, which say I should expect 26°C temp raise for every W | That would make 104°C, which looks like what I have here.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon so I'm not really sure if these temperatures are ok for the motor, or if the motor is designed to run for short bursts of time only (as I suppose would happen in a typewriter, where it would be used as the carriage drive)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you provide the wrong circuit we can oblige with the wrong answer :-)

If the supply voltage being used is the same or lower than before then mu answer dos not explain what is happening.

If the supply voltage is greater than before then the zener may be not providing the isolation intended.

What is the old supply voltage ?
 What is the new MEASURED in circuit running supply voltage?
 What is the zener voltage?

If Vzener is < V_supply_new_actual then what I describe below will be happening to some extent.

---

**The problem is that you are shorting the windings with the internal diodes in the ULN2003.**

As you can see from your drawing (even though it tends not to be intuitive at first glance) -  each centre tapped winding is like two magnetically coupled inductors or two halves of a transformer winding. When you connect the centre tap to V+ and ground one end the other end rises to 2 x V+ - or tries to. BUT each driven output is connected via a diode to com (anode to driver, cathode to com). When you ground one end of the winding and the other end is connected to V+ via a diode you are trying to drive the supply with 2 x supply (less a diode drop). Something has to give. As you have discovered.

The internal "catch diodes" are intended to return energy in eg inductive  spikes from isolated coils but are not suited to this role.

With a stepper you may not get substantial inductive kicks so the com diodes may not be needed. YMMV.

**Fix:**

Remove the battery connection to "com" and one of:

- In the unlikely event that you have a 2 x V+ rail, connect com to that. That would be a near perfect solution. If you connect com to a capacitor you will get a 2 x V+ supply :-).
- Leave it floating (check with oscilloscope or magic smoke)
- or connect com via a resistor to supply
- Connect a zener from com to ground (Vzener > 2 x Vsupply) or com to V+ (Vzener > V+). Zener cathode to com in each case so com can rise to 2 x V+ without zener conducting.
- or connect com via a resistor to a capacitor with other terminal grounded,  with a second resistor from capacitor to ground.

Just leaving COM open circuit MAY be OK.

The above schemes with capacitor and resistor provide a load for inductive spikes. They also load the transformer formed by the two halves so the resistor to the capacitor is to reduce the unwanted loading. The resistor to ground drains the cap. Dimension as required.

---

**Doing it right:**

MOST circuits on the internet which show a ULN200x driving a stepper motor with centre tapped windings show com (incorrectly) connected to V+.

The easy practical test of my assertion is to either disconnect com (slight risk of ULN2003 dying) or connect to V+ with a zener as above, the monitor com with an oscilloscope. Or connect a capacitor with voltage rating > 2 x V+  from com to ground, operate stepper and measure capacitor voltage. Voltages of ~=2 x V+ should appear.

__

Here is one circuit which almost gets it right - except he has the zener diode polarity reversed. As shown the zener acts like a low grade diode with the same polarity as the ULN200x internal diodes. Reverse it and it lets com rise to V+ + Vzener.

[image]

[The above diagram is from here]( 
http://ssecganesh.blogspot.com/2008/05/driving-stepper-motor-using-uln2003.html)

---

Hooray hooray ! - here is somebody who has got it right ! :-)

[image]

The above circuit [is from here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/26887294@N05/5708553852/) - he doesn't explain the use of the zener - see my comments above.

Comment: you said "The above schemes with capacitor and resistor provide a load for inductive spikes" but I don't see any link to any schematic. Would help to see it to understand your post.

Comment: @nerochiaro- Do you still have the driver board from the typewriter? See if the com pin is tied to V+.

Comment: @SteveR From what I can see the COM pin of the ULN2003A is connected to V+, but there's a zener diode in between. I didn't include it my circuit since I thought it was put there to protect the power supply from back current.

Comment: First thing: my question didn't have the "wrong" schematic as you implied. The schematic shows the circuit I built that overheated the motor, and it didn't have the zener in it.


Now, following your good explanation I extracted the zener from the same old typewriter where I found the motor, and installed it in my own circuit.
 

The new circuit is as shown [here](http://i.imgur.com/idDbA.png)


The zener is an [HZ361](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.net/datasheet-pdf/view/99101/RENESAS/HZ36-1.html)


All that said, my original problem is not solved: the motor still runs very hot.

Comment: @nerochiaro - Is the zener polarity correct? - see above.| Is Vzener > Vsupply_now? see above. | "I didn't include it in my circuit" is/was ambiguous. I assumed you meant your circuit diagram, as you did not tell me what you have told us since.| If you leave the com pin open or use a resistor and cap (say 1k to 10k and say 10 uF to 100 uF) what happens? See above. | Is there anything else you have left out or added but not told us? | If you have unused ULN2003 sections you should ground their inputs and leave their outputs OC.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon sorry for the misunderstanding. I updated my original question. Please let's use that as the basis for any further discussion. Thank you for all your help so far :)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I did some further experiments based on your proposed answer and your questions, and added the results to my original question. I would really appreciate it if you could have a look at them when you have a spare minute. Thank you.

Comment: Since the ULN2003 outputs are rated for 50 V, the zener to COM is intended to speed turnoff of windings, by allowing the inductive kick to reach a nominal 24 volts rather than 12. Since V = L di/dt, doubling the clamp voltage halves the discharge time for the winding field.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast What you say is correct in the general case but does not address the specific situation here. I'll summarise what I said in my original answer. IF you have a  stepper with a centre tapped winding, and the CT is connected to supply, then when one end is grounded to drive the stepper, the other open end rises to 2 x supply due to transformer action. If there is a hard connection from COM to supply (as some ccts show) then the open winding is clamped to V+- plus a diode drop instead of the 2 x V+ it should be allowed to rise to, at minimum. ...

Comment: ... The effect is that driver power attempts to couple to supply :-(.  A zener of at least V+ voltage rating allows correct operation in that case. | Where a general purpose inductor is driven or a stepper with no interwinding couplings then your time constant explanation applies.

Answer (score 1):

I've been pulling a typewriter apart too for the motors, etc. Stepper motors can often run hot, as even while idle. They normally have full current running through them continuously (unlike a DC motor which only need current to move it). You may well find that there was further circuitry in your typewriter which can turn the stepper motor supply voltage off when it's not needed.